# SQL: How to grab the earliest date available, and set as string if there's no date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to write a query and output to an excel file which outputs all of a members mortgages into a cell, but grabbing their earliest maturity date first.

For example, the column would look like this for a each member:

`John Doe - Account#: 1234  Maturity Date: 2020-01-28   Account#: 5678  Maturity Date: 2020-01-29   Account#: 7890  Maturity Date: No Maturity Date`

If they have a mortgage with no maturity date, it would just set the date to output text like 'No Maturity Date'.

I have the query to output everything into one line, but for some reason it's setting some of members earliest maturity dates to 'No Maturity Date' when they indeed have a date.

My SQL query currently looks like this for:

```html
;WITH Mtg AS(
 SELECT DISTINCT PartyID 
 Balance,
 [Account Number],
 [Full Name], 
 COALESCE(CAST([Maturity Date] AS VARCHAR(30)), CAST([Maturity Date] AS VARCHAR(30)) + SPACE(2), 'No Maturity Date' + SPACE(2)) AS [Maturity Date]
FROM #Mortgages
```

After that, I would format it for output which looks like this:

```html
)
, Mtg1 AS(
 SELECT DISTINCT 
  outputLogic.DescriptionList
 , SUM(M.Balance) OVER(PARTITION BY M.PartyID ORDER BY M.PartyID) AS TotalMaturingBalance
 , [Maturity Date]
 , M.[Full Name]
 , M.PartyID
 FROM Mtg AS M
 CROSS APPLY(
  SELECT (STUFF((SELECT'| [Full Name] +'- '+ SPACE(2) 
    + 'Account#: ' + [Account Number] + SPACE(2) 
    + 'Mat. Date: ' + [Maturity Date] + Space(2)
    + 'Mat. Bal:'+ '$'+CAST(M.Balance AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + SPACE(2)
  FROM Mtg AS M1
  WHERE M1.PartyID=M.PartyID
  FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 5, '')  ) AS DescriptionList
 ) outputLogic
```

I have my original script, which doesn't account for the 'No Maturity Date' text that's in production now.  When I run my edited script (the one I posted above), the same member which has both types of mortgages (maturity date and no maturity date) in the production script would have only the one correct Account # and Maturity Date, but in my edited script it would output just the Account # and 'No Maturity Date'

My question is, what would I need to change in my script to output the members earliest maturity date, and then 'No Maturity Date' in the same column for the member scenario I explained above?

**EDIT**: Adding Sample data

```
Member Name: Jane Doe
Account #: 10000000  Mat. Date: 2020-04-20    Mat. Bal:$20000
Account #: 10000001  Mat. Date: No Maturity Date    Mat. Bal:$100
```

In my edited version, the SQL I posted above, only the data for `10000001` would be outputted, in the production version only the `10000000` would be outputted.

My desired output would look like this:

```
 Jane Doe- Account #: 10000000 Mat. Date: 2020-04-20  Mat. Bal:$20000
 Account #: 10000001 Mat. Date: No Maturity Date  Mat. Bal:$100
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added some more details, thanks